# No se adjunta fichero al email enviado, en Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Tengo un formulario donde se adjunta un pdf. El resto de campos los recibo y se añaden correctamente en el mail. El mail llega correctamente pero no me adjunta el PDF. Este es mi código

```
introducir el código aquí

  public function sendMail(){
    $to = 'info@email.com';
    $nombre = $this->request->getVar('firstName');
    $apellidos = $this->request->getVar('lastName');
    $email = $this->request->getVar('userEmail');
    $telefono = $this->request->getVar('userTelefono');
    $message = $this->request->getVar('userMessage');


    $mensaje = 'Nombre:' . $nombre . '<br>';
    $mensaje .= 'Apellidos:' . $apellidos . '<br>';
    $mensaje .= 'Email:' . $email . '<br>';
    $mensaje .= 'Teléfono:' . $telefono . '<br>';
    $mensaje .= 'Mensaje:' . $message . '<br>';



    $email = \Config\Services::email();
    $session = \Config\Services::session();
    $subject = 'Formulario Contacto';
    $email->setTo($to);
    $email->setSubject($subject);
    $email->setFrom('info@email.com');
    $email->setSubject($subject);
    $email->setMessage($mensaje);



    //Send mail
    if($email->send()){

        $session->setFlashdata("email_sent","Gracias. Hemos recibido tu mensaje.");

        return redirect()->to(base_url('/contacto'));

    }else{
        $session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Ha habido un error al enviar el correo.");

        print_r($email->printDebugger(['headers']));
        //$email->load->view('email_form');
    }

}
```

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser el problema de que no se adjunte el PDF?

Comment: En qué linea haces  el adjuntas el PDF

Comment: En ninguna linea indicas que se adjunte el archivo PDF.